# Is an EU covid pass with two doses of Sputnik and one dose of Pfizer valid?

Tags: covid-19, vaccinations

My wife got two doses of the Sputnik V covid vaccine in Russia, and then one dose of the Pfizer vaccine in Sweden.

When getting the Pfizer shot in Sweden, she explained that she already got two doses of Sputnik, the nurse asked various other doctors there what she should do about it, they checked her Russian vaccination certificate, and finally ended up registering it as a third dose.

I found this pretty surprising given that Sputnik V is not recognized in Sweden, but the fact is that she now has a vaccination certificate saying "dose 3 of 3, Pfizer".

I'm wondering if this certificate will be accepted in countries that require it. One the one hand, it technically shouldn't be, as Sputnik isn't recognized and Pfizer requires two doses, but on the other hand the certificate doesn't appear to mention Sputnik anywhere.

So does the covid pass contain information about the first two doses or is it indistinguishable from a pass with three doses of Pfizer?

Comment: What do you observe if you load the certificate into e.g. [the German CovPass-App](https://www.digitaler-impfnachweis-app.de/en/)? Supposedly it has the ability to check if your certificate is valid for travel to various countries, though I suppose it may be unreliable in corner cases like this.

Comment: The German app cannot be downloaded in Sweden, so I tried with the French app instead and it said that it is valid.

Comment: The wording is not clear: **must** the primary 2-dose vaccination be valid in the country of issue (i.e. would the country issue a certificate for each if those 2 doses)? [EUR-Lex - 32021D2301 - EN - EUR-Lex - ANNEX 5.2    Booster doses](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32021D2301): *3/3 indicates the administration of a booster dose following a **primary 2-dose vaccination series**.* If not, then the '3/3' should not have been issued. The checking application will probably assume that the first 2 were valid and accept the 3rd as valid.

Comment: "as Sputnik isn't recognized ..." That is not true. Some countries accept Sputnik, eg Greece.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It must be recognized in the country that **issues** the certificate (which is Sweden). Since Sweden does **not** recognises Sputnik, the **primary 2-dose vaccination series** condition is **not** fulfilled. The issued certificate should have shown '1/2' and **not** '3/3'.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I see what you mean. It's not at all clear when reading the question that they mean "Sputnik is not recognized in Sweden". I assumed they were talking about EU covid passes in general.

Comment: It will be valid. I have used the Danish `Coronapas` for traveling to Germany and they always check the last dose. So it should be fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all to answer your question: Yes, the pass will be accepted. It is indeed indistinguishable from a pass issued to someone who has received three shots of Pfizer or for example two shots of AstraZeneca/Moderna followed by a third shot of Pfizer. The reason is that the certificate only contains details, for example manufacturer and date of administration, of the *last* vaccine and no details about previous vaccines except the number of vaccines administered in total.

*Note*: I am not saying that your wife is legally fulfilling the requirement of having a recognized vaccination sequence with a booster shot, just that the certificate indicates that she has so.

It might seem as if the certificate was issued incorrectly, but it is not at all obvious. The EU regulations on how to encode different scenarios in the vaccination certificate simply do not cover this particular situation.

Comment: Upvoted, but I would say the health provider made the mistake. OP's wife should have got a first dose instead of a third, previous to this vaccination she had zero shots of a recognized vaccine.

Comment: @Anders It is not up to the issuer, but to the acceptor of the certificate to decise wether the vaccine type is recognized or not. Which vaccine types are accepted differs from country to country and it is not even per se incorrect, at least how I read the regulation, to issue a certificate for an unrecognized vaccine type. If the Swedes had issued certificates for the two first vaccines, the certificates would have reflected that the Sputnik vaccine had been used and the acceptor could then decide not to accept the certificate. That detail is lost in the certificate for the third vaccine.

Comment: @TorEinarJarnbjo true in the generic case. But the health provider in this case registered the dose as number 3 in the Swedish vaccination registry. Since she previously had got 0 (by Sweden) recognized doses I still blame the health provider.

Comment: To make things even more confusing, I found the following webpage: https://vardgivarguiden.se/utveckling/2019-ncov/vaccination/godkanda-vaccin-mot-covid-19/. It seems to be a guide for health care providers in the Stockholm region, and it says that someone who received two doses of Sputnik V should be "considered fully vaccinated" (betraktas som grundvaccinerad). They don't explain exactly what they mean by that, but maybe that's why the Pfizer dose got registered as dose number 3?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie  maybe that's why the qr code should contain all the vaccine types if better designed, since different countries have different vaccine requirements, and they evolve over time.

Comment: Interestingly this does not seem to apply to a UK pass. Source: friend who has 2 vaccines delivered in EU, and a booster in the UK. UK app shows third shot as a third shot, but will not generate a certificate.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The base45 zlib-compressed data takes up about 20-25% of the available amount of data that a QR CODE can store (2953 bytes). It is **not** a database that can store an unlimited amount of data. [QR CODE max char length - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764370)

Comment: @MarkJohnson Just add a link to a website that contains the information.

Comment: @FrankDernoncourt Except that those QR codes are designed to work even without internet access. Also there are way more potential security risks if everyone's health information is available online through simple links.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie add a password to access the website in the qr code and use some hard to guess url with some ID string. People have typically access to Internet, especially in check in points. They could also encode the vaccine information in the QR code in a more compressed way if they really want it to work 100% offline

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt People do not *always* have access to the internet and requiring an internet connection to verify the certificate would have made it useless for most purposes. I agree though, that they should have defined a much less verbose data format, allowing more information to be stored in the QR code.

Answer (score 22):

This has been a contentious issue in Hungary as well, where lot of people have been vaccinated with Sputnik V last year. One of the Hungarian EU MEPs have therefore asked the EU commission if a dose (or two dose) of Sputnik V followed by a single dose of an EU approved vaccine (like Pfizer or Moderna) will make it valid for cross border EU travel, or not.

The answer was that it is **indeed valid**, and **has to be accepted when crossing borders within the EU**, meaning a dose of Pfizer that followed one or two doses of Sputnik V will indeed make you vaccinated(*) when you wish to cross borders within the EU. In short: a border guard that tries to check your full vaccination history can **not** deny you entry, even if they see that you only have a single dose of an EU approved vaccine.

However this is **only true for checks when crossing the borders within the EU, or entering the EU itself from a 3rd country**. Member states can **still set local laws on who is considered vaccinated or not**. For example you might still be considered unvaccinated by a member state and not allowed to enter a restaurant. Countries which have a vaccination mandate (like Austria) could still consider you unvaccinated. However other answers have already mentioned that any member state using the current EU Covid Pass to check vaccination status will unlikely to notice that your vaccinations include non-EU approved ones - but there's still a very-very small, but non-zero chance that you might face issues.

Also this only applies within the EU, technically any other country accepting the EU Covid Pass, but doesn't consider the Sputnik V vaccine valid (for example the UK) could technically still consider you unvaccinated on entry. As others mentioned this is again unlikely - border guards usually just have a glance on your pass, checking that it looks valid and is showing 2/2 or 3/3 doses. I personally have never seen a border guard neither in the UK nor in the EU checking whether the QR code is valid or not for example.

[There](https://mfor.hu/cikkek/makro/keleti-vakcinaval-is-lehet-utazni-az-eu-ban.html)'s [plenty](https://www.portfolio.hu/global/20220202/vege-a-tiltasnak-megoldodott-a-szputnyikkal-es-a-sinopharmmal-oltott-magyarok-utazasa-524517) of [Hungarian sources](https://infostart.hu/belfold/2022/02/02/megoldodott-a-keleti-vakcinaval-oltottak-utazasa-az-unioban) for the announcement, but I also found an [English one](https://hungarytoday.hu/eastern-western-vaccines-european-union-eu-vaccine-restrictions-hungary-accepted/) as well:

> **Travel of Those Vaccinated with Eastern Vaccine in EU Resolved**
>
> (...)
>
> According to Ujhelyi’s announcement, Didier Reynders has made it clear to him that **all EU Member States are obliged to accept EU vaccines administered for one or two eastern vaccines as a condition for entry without restrictions**, i.e. without costly testing for the Hungarians concerned.
>
> (...)
>
> The MSZP MEP called the announcement good news, but also pointed out that the EU institutions have **only made border crossing and entry free of restrictions**, while it is always necessary to find out about individual restrictions within the borders of the member states (restaurants, public transport, use of social spaces, etc.), as these are the responsibility of the countries concerned and may differ from one another.

Also note that the current EU Covid Pass might change in the future as well. [There are plans](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/eu-commission-proposes-several-changes-to-the-eu-digital-covid-certificate/) to add more information to it, like previous vaccinations, which could make it more visible that you had two Sputnik Vs before the Pfizer:

> The EU Commission has recommended some limited amendments to the Regulation (...) Making sure that the correct number of COVID-19 vaccine doses is included in the certificates even when the EU citizen has received the doses in the different Member States.

Again this should have no effect on entering the EU / crossing the borders, but might affect your ability to use local services which require proof of vaccinated status. However it is still unlikely (given the relaxed verification done in most countries) that this is going to cause issues for you.

---

(*): do note, vaccine expiration still applies though, so if you only had two doses (single Sputnik V folllowed by a single Pfizer), and the second dose was more than 6 month ago you might still be considered unvaccinated until you get your booster.

Comment: *but non-zero chance that this might get you in trouble* => there won't be any *trouble* even if noticed. At worst they won't let you eat in a restaurant, which isn't a big deal. There can be no fines or penalties whatsoever. Just calling that out in case someone might be worried about getting into trouble.

Comment: Depends on what you consider trouble. Not being let in into a restaurant with your mates might be called "trouble". But yeah, it shouldn't be any big deal.

Comment: On the other hand not sure how this would go for countries where vaccinations are going to be mandatory, like Austria.

Comment: @JonathanReez There are no fines or penalties for not being vaccinated, but sure there can be for falsely claiming you are when (legally) you aren't. Unlikely it will ever happen, but not totally impossible.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation of the rules I have ever seen, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is an EU covid pass with two doses of Sputnik and one dose of Pfizer valid?

The vaccine type requirements depend on the requirements on wherever you go. E.g., Sputnik isn't valid if entering France. https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/FRA/7001

> All travellers aged 12 and older can enter France if their ‘EU Digital COVID Certificate’ contains one of the following:
>
> - Proof of full vaccination. Accepted vaccines: Pfizer, Moderna, AstraZeneca, Johnson & Johnson.
>
>   - 7 days after the second injection for double injection vaccines (Pfizer, Moderna, AstraZeneca);
>   - 28 days post injection for vaccines with a single injection (Johnson & Johnson);
>   - 7 days after the injection for vaccines in people who have had COVID-19 (only single injection).
> - Proof of recovery from COVID-19. Validity: 180 days.
> - Negative molecular or antigen test result. Validity: 24 or 48 hours.

However, as discussed in the comments below, the EU covid pass was badly designed and is missing the vaccine type information except for the last dose, which means that the type of the other doses currently don't matter from a practical standpoint as long as the provider gave you the certificate. One can use https://danstonpass.fr/ to see what the QR code of the EU COVID certificate contains. Note that it is likely to still constitute an illegal entry (one would have to check how the rule is written to confirm).

Comment: I tried to scan it with the French app (TAC Verif) and it recognizes it as valid. So even if it is indeed technically invalid in France, it looks like it would be accepted anyway.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie interesting, try https://danstonpass.fr/

Comment: So you claim that the certificate contains information about all doses? I believe it only contains the last one.

Comment: @Anders idk, the quote suggests so, however I'm reading otherwise so I don't think so. Best is to use https://danstonpass.fr/ or some other QR decoding program to see for oneself.

Comment: I just tried danstonpass.fr and it only shows information on the third dose. No mention of Sputnik whatsoever.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie sounds like you're off the hook! didn't see any extra info in other QR decoding program I've seen on github. Whoever made those passes are a bunch of idiots or I missed something  (privacy constraints maybe). But at least they're good for open sourcing, eg https://github.com/eu-digital-green-certificates/dgc-certlogic-android -> repository of the source code of the EU Digital COVID Certificate Certlogic for Android.

Comment: Yes, you did miss something. Each QR-Code contains the information about 1 certificate (as with all QR-Codes). The issuer is expected to issue it correctly.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the lack of information regarding all the vaccine types and dates is what surprises me, as it removes one possible check in case the issuer doesn't understand the vaccine requirements. I indeed saw the certificate in the output from some QR decoder programs, I'll update the answer when I am back on a computer.